# Effect of repeating subject in "zwar .. aber" construction

Tags: usage, style

From [Frankfurter Allgemeine](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/mohammed-karikaturen-was-heilig-ist-13374950.html):

> Auf dem Weg nach Manila hat sich das Oberhaupt der katholischen Kirche nicht dem fast europaweiten Chor „Je suis Charlie“ angeschlossen. Er verurteilte den Terroranschlag von Paris zwar scharf, **er** kritisierte aber auch die Karikaturen als eine Beleidigung religiöser Gefühle.

Here, the subject *er* is repeated in the "zwar .. aber" construction. I think it is usually left out, as in

> Er verurteilte ... zwar scharf, kritisierte aber auch ...

So I imagine that the subject is repeated to create some effect. But what effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second mention of *er* destroys the usual speech melody of a "zwar … aber" expression as it creates the feeling of a new sentence beginning. Hereby, the reader is aroused after the comma and will be aware of something unusually important following.

In spoken language, there would be a short break before the *er*, besides the word *auch* might be clearly stressed and sometimes been followed by another break.

In your example, this makes very much sense as the pope is depicting the terrorists' point of view while the crowd is mainly accusing and shouting at them, making the second main clause in the sentence crucial. In general, the repetition of the subject could just as well be the result of an inattention on behalf of the author without any particular intention.

(In this answer, I am assuming that the author was indeed aware of the effect.)

Comment: I especially like that you mention both intentional and unintentional use of the second "er".